# Redirect from one controller to another with changed body and headers

Tags: java, spring, rest, redirect, request

I have generic controller which has encoded request body. I would like this controller decode body and set this decoded body and  redirect to specific controller. Below is my controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{type}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String save(@RequestBody String base64Body, @PathVariable("type") String type) throws IOException {

    String json = decompress(Base64.getDecoder().decode(base64Body));

    //now I'd like set json to request body, change header, and redirect to "type" controller
    return format("redirect:/%s/save", type);
}
```

Above code should call my controller from addres /type/save with decoded body, Is it even possible? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
format("redirect:/%s/save/json=%s", type, json);
```

OR just autowire the redirect target controller to the main one and call the method directly without http transport.

Comment: What actually this "json=" determines?

Comment: I mean you can pass the json as a request parameter.